# Force next div to go to next row

Tags: html, css

I have some structure like this:

```css
.divParent{
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

.div2{
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="divParent">
  <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="divNew">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

I want `divNew` to go to next line and not get overlapped by content of `divParent`. I tried so many things but nothing is working out.

I know, I can use `<br />` tag to do this but I don't want to use that. Is there any other solution.

Comment: you tagged this with bootstrap .. where is bootstrap ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Removed that. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: It works like intended in your snippet?

Comment: @MarkBaijens Yes. But I want to push divNew to new line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `flex`

```css
.divParent{
  clear:both;
  height: 100px;
}

.div1 {
  height: 40px;
  background: blue;
}

.div2{
  height: 150px;
  background: yellow
}
.divParent, .divNew {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.divNew { 
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="divParent">
  <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
  <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
</div>
<div class="divNew">
  <span>Hello</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The line "//Add this line" blocks out the height statement on the divParent element.

Comment: Gone. Not sure it's a reason to downvote, perhaps just a comment to mention it.

Comment: Without that line the height of the divs does not match the css (div2: 150px etc). And I wasn't the one who downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to remove the height, your second div is actually causing an issue. It's bigger than parent. So either increase the parent or decrease div2.

Comment: those heights are dynamic, so can't change those.